# Solidity fund transfer is redirecting to another address

Tags: solidity, transactions, blockchain, remix

I am trying to send funds in solidity using the below code

```
/ SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract SendEther
{
    function sendAmount() payable public
    {
        address _to = 0x90E3EC58Eb437204ad071339d6CE97740e7eadd0;
        payable(_to).transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

However, I am getting a entirely different address on metamask wallet.[image: Please check the metamask wallet sender address here]

Answer (score 1):

I'm speculating that the frontend is trying to call `contract.SendAmount{value: ???}()`, and metamask is asking you to approve the call to the contract. So the address you're seeing is actually the contract address.

You don't need to approve every individual operation inside the contract's function, so you should never see you hardcoded `_to` address in metamask.

Comment: Actually I am using remix IDE to test my code. I was following a tutorial and performed the exact operation. However I am not getting the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Transfers performed by a contract are usually called "internal transaction".

Unfortunately Metamask doesn't support displaying internal transaction.

In your case it is showing the contract interaction executin the `sendAmount` function.

Comment: So, may I know a way to get the job done

Comment: @ManiDeepakTelaprolu What are you trying to do? The contract does transfer whatever ether amount it receives to the address `0x90E3EC58Eb437204ad071339d6CE97740e7eadd0`. If you want Metamask to display an "internal transaction" that's not possible.

Comment: When I executed the above smart contract, the funds got redirected to another address. I check on etherscan also. Funds redirected. If you don't mind can you please run the contract on your remix IDE?

Comment: @ManiDeepakTelaprolu Do you have the transaction hash?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to help me. I got to know the issue and funds were reflected in the state of transaction

Comment: @ManiDeepakTelaprolu I don't understand what are you asking? If you executed the contract in the question then it should have sent the ether to the recipient wallet. If that didn't occur then you executed the wrong contract.